# Why am I seeing negative factor loadings when using the factor-analyzer module in pandas and limiting the model to 1 factor?

Tags: pandas, stata, factor-analysis

I am trying to learn how to perform factor analysis in Pandas using the [factor-analyzer module](https://factor-analyzer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/factor_analyzer.html). I'm checking my work by running the same analysis in Stata.

The initial, exploratory factor analysis showed one factor with an eigenvalue greater than 1 (in both Stata and Pandas). In Stata, I ran my **factor** command to only include one factor:

**factor varlist, pcf factors(1)**

In Pandas, I ran the following:

**FactorAnalyzer(n_factors=1, rotation=None, method="principal", impute='drop')**

I expected to see the same factor loading charts in Stata and Pandas, and they were *almost* the same, except that the signs were reversed (all negative in Pandas).

I then reran the FactorAnalyzer (Pandas) model without constraining it to one factor (e.g., I allowed the default 3 factors), the factor loadings for Factor 1 are identical to the results from Stata.

I assume the programs must be doing something different when you constrain the model to 1 factor (maybe Stata is just suppressing additional factors in the output?), but I'd like to be sure I understand what's going on. Any insight/help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a common question about the method and arises from the fact that multiple solutions make sense when fitting an ellipse (ellipsoid).  See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88880/does-the-sign-of-scores-or-of-loadings-in-pca-or-fa-have-a-meaning-may-i-revers for lengthy discussion and explanation.

Comment: Thanks Nick! guess I was not as thorough as I thought when looking for a similar question. I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: You don't have to mark this as a duplicate. (Don't you need more reputation to do that?) You could just delete it. If's a fine question, just much answered and not really about programming.